# Import-SPWeb Fatal Error [-2146231999]: The Enumeration constraint failed

Tags: sharepoint-server, site, import

A fatal error occurred while running Import-SPWeb in SharePoint 2016. Here is the error message in the import.log.

```
[6/29/2023 2:08:52 PM] [List] [Documents] [Documents] [8f9dbc3e-f3e0-4cc7-b7d5-e3ff225e94a1][Progress] Importing
[6/29/2023 2:08:52 PM] [List] [Documents] [Documents] [8f9dbc3e-f3e0-4cc7-b7d5-e3ff225e94a1]  [ExtendedVerbose] Creating
[6/29/2023 2:08:52 PM] [FatalError] [-2146231999] [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException] [The 'Type' attribute is invalid - The value 'WorkflowStarting' is invalid according to its datatype 'urn:deployment-manifest-schema:SPEventReceiverType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.] 
*** Inner exception:
[-2146231999] [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException] [The Enumeration constraint failed.] 
[6/29/2023 2:08:52 PM] [Debug]    at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.CheckAttributeValue(Object value, SchemaAttDef attdef)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateAttribute(String lName, String ns, XmlValueGetter attributeValueGetter, String attributeStringValue, XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo)
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ValidateAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent()
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean defattr)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadOuterXml()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.ParseObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.DeserializeObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject, DeploymentObject envelope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeObjects()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
[6/29/2023 2:08:52 PM] [Progress] Import did not complete.
[6/29/2023 2:08:52 PM] Finish Time: 6/29/2023 2:08:52 PM.
```

I could not find "WorkflowStarting" in all Manifest.xml, Manifest1.xml, Manifest2.xml, etc.

Could anyone help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Found out the issue. SPEventReceiverType enumeration doesn't have "WorkflowStarting" value. However, in one or more SharePoint lists on the source SharePoint web, "WorkflowStarting" was specified in event receivers. After removing such event receivers by PowerShell, and then exporting the web, the error didn't occur during importing the web.

Comment: While I post the above solution as an answer. I received the following message: "
Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from your account because most of your answers need improvement or do not sufficiently answer the question. See the Help Center to learn more." I followed the steps and didn't find anything wrong in my previous answers. Anyway...